# Valores JsonResult são recebidos pelo javascript mas campos não recebem valor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Função javascript recebe valores mas campos não estão recebendo os valores.

**Função do Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetSequencia(DateTime dataAbate)
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var lote = db.Lotes.Where(p => p.DataAbate == dataAbate).ToList();

            if (lote.Count <= 0)
            {
                var loteNull = db.Lotes.ToList();

                loteNull.Add(new Lote
                {
                    SequenciaInicial = 123,
                    SequenciaFinal = 456
                });

                return Json(loteNull);
            }

            return Json(lote);
        }
```

**Função Javascript dentro do SECTION SCRIPTS**

```
    @section Scripts {


        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#DataAbate").change(function () {
                    $("#SequenciaInicial").empty();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetSequencia")',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: { dataAbate: $("#DataAbate").val() },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $.each(data, function (i, data) {

                                $("#SequenciaInicial").append(data.SequenciaInicial);
                                $("#SequenciaFinal").append(data.SequenciaFinal);

                            });
                        },
                        error: function (ex) {
                            alert('Falha ao buscar Proprietario.' + ex);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                })            
            });




}
```

**Campos que não estão recebendo os valores**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SequenciaInicial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SequenciaInicial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SequenciaInicial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SequenciaFinal, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SequenciaFinal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SequenciaFinal, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O [append](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp) é utilizado para inserir conteúdo no final de elementos. O correto é você utilizar o `val` para adicionar valores.

Comment: Outra coisa, seu Edit for não tem ID. Pode modificar para: `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SequenciaInicial, new { id = "SequenciaInicial") })`

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia Cyberiacs, para serializar json em minhas aplicações Rest eu uso NewtonsoftJson - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Tem que ser feito uma configuração no Startup.js no metodo Configuration incluindo a seguinte linha.

```
var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>
().First();
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new 
CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Depois disso basta apenas nos seus controllers, retornar o objeto da seginte forma

```
Return Ok(seuObjecto);
```

seuObjeto deve ser o objeto c#, assim o plugin do newtonsoft irá serialziar o js para você.

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Mude o código:

```
$.each(data, function (i, data) {  
   $("#SequenciaInicial").append(data.SequenciaInicial); 
   $("#SequenciaFinal").append(data.SequenciaFinal);
});
```

para:

```
$(data).each(function (idx, elem) {  
   $("#SequenciaInicial").append(elem.SequenciaInicial); 
   $("#SequenciaFinal").append(elem.SequenciaFinal);
});
```

Basicamente a mudança é no uso de nome diferente da variável `data` na função `$.each`.